# UPDATE takes long time on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have tables "Products" 300,000 rows, and "Imported_Products" 4,000 rows. Also I have view "View_Imported_Products" which is based on "Imported_Products" to make it well-formed.

When I run UPDATE:

```
UPDATE Products SET DateDeleted = GETDATE()
WHERE Suppiler = 'Supplier1' AND SKU NOT IN (SELECT SKU FROM View_Imported_Products)
```

It takes a lot of time about 1 minute even if I run it second time and no rows update.

I have added non-clustered indexes on Products.SKU and View_Imported_Products.SKU, also I changed NOT IN to NOT EXISTS

```
UPDATE Products SET DateDeleted = GETDATE() FROM Products P
WHERE Supplier = 'Supplier1' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT SKU FROM View_Imported_Products I WHERE P.SKU=I.SKU)
```

But it still takes about 16 seconds to run.

What I'm doing wrong, and how to improve that update to run it fast.

Appreciate any help.

Thank you

**UPDATED**

1. SELECT SKU FROM View_ImportedProducts - runs very fast, it takes 00:00:00 sec
2. Changed query to use LEFT JOIN, instead NOT EXISTS - doesn't help much
3. ```
   SELECT * FROM Products AS P
   WHERE P.Supplier = 'Supplier1' AND DateDeleted IS NULL
   AND 
   NOT EXISTS
   (
       SELECT 
           SKU 
       FROM View_ImportedProducts AS I 
       WHERE P.SKU = I.SKU
   )
   ```

   takes also long time to execute

Comment: do you really need to use the view?, can't you just use `Imported_Products` directly?

Comment: What does the Execution plan look like? How many records are you trying to update? Are there indexes on the values of the records you are updating?

Comment: Do you have anything built on the products table, like an indexed view or something similar?

Comment: How long does it take to run the view? Can you share what's in it?

Comment: Depending on when you run it and if you are worried about locking, you can try tablock.

Comment: Yes,  I need to use View, because I also Update other fields, like price, which is string in Imported_Products table, check for nulls, and make rtrim/ltrim

Comment: There is nothing built on Products table

Comment: Please provide your execution plan.

Comment: Again, what does the execution plan look like? In 95% of situations this alone can find performance problems in a query. See [Display an Actual Execution Plan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189562.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Resolved it by added Non-clustered index to "Imported_Products".SKU field. My mistake was I added non-clustered index on "View_Imported_Products".SKU, instead of original table. Thank you all for help and replies!

Answer (score 0):

Why not using joins

```
UPDATE Products SET DateDeleted = GETDATE()     FROM Products P
Left join View_Imported_Products I On     P.SKU=I.SKU
Where I.Sku is null
```

And you have to create non clustered indexes on p.sku and i.sku

Comment: why would this join be faster?. In SQL Server, `NOT EXISTS` typically performs better than `LEFT JOIN ...IS NO NULL`

Comment: Joins are better then using dependent subquery.

Comment: `SELECT SKU FROM View_Imported_Products I WHERE P.SKU=I.SKU` is loading more data before filtering them

Comment: can you back that up with some source?, because **[I'm pretty sure that for SQL Server that's wrong](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/)**

Comment: left join doesn't help much, same long time

Answer (score 0):

If a lot of rows (tens of thousands) are being updated you are creating a big hit on the log. If this is so you want to update either 1000 or 10000 rows at a time and then commit. Your transaction will have a much smaller impact on the transaction log and will execute a lot faster.